# How to make data to be shown in tabular form in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi I am creating a bot that makes points table/leaderboard , below is the code which works really nice.

```
def check(ctx):
    return lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel


async def get_input_of_type(func, ctx):
    while True:
        try:
            msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check(ctx))
            return func(msg.content)
        except ValueError:
            continue

@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.send("How many total teams are there?")
    t = await get_input_of_type(int, ctx)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"__**{ctx.guild.name} Results:**__", color=0x03f8fc,timestamp= ctx.message.created_at)
    
    lst = []
    
    for i in range(t):
        await ctx.send(f"Enter team {i+1} name :")
        teamname = await get_input_of_type(str, ctx)
        await ctx.send("How many kills did they get?")
        firstnum = await get_input_of_type(int, ctx)
        await ctx.send("How much Position points did they score?")
        secondnum = await get_input_of_type(int, ctx)
        lst.append((teamname, firstnum, secondnum))  # append 
        
    lstSorted = sorted(lst, key = lambda x: int(x[1]) + int(x[2],),reverse=True) # sort   
    for teamname, firstnum, secondnum in lstSorted:  # process embed
        embed.add_field(name=f'**{teamname}**', value=f'Kills: {firstnum}\nPosition Pt: {secondnum}\nTotal Pt: {firstnum+secondnum}',inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The result looks something like this:

[image]

But I want to know, can I do something to get the result in tabular form like The Team Name , positions points , total pts, kill pts written in a row and the results printed below them (I really don't if that made you understand what I am trying to say.)

Below image will help you understand ,

[image]

So I want the result to be in following format. I can't think of a way doing it , if you can answer this please do so, That would be a very great help!
Thanks.

Comment: Check discord embeds. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed

Answer (score 13):

With [table2ascii](https://table2ascii.readthedocs.io), you can easily generate ascii tables and put them in codeblocks on Discord.

You may also choose to use it in an Embed.

````py
from table2ascii import table2ascii as t2a, PresetStyle

# In your command:
output = t2a(
    header=["Rank", "Team", "Kills", "Position Pts", "Total"],
    body=[[1, 'Team A', 2, 4, 6], [2, 'Team B', 3, 3, 6], [3, 'Team C', 4, 2, 6]],
    style=PresetStyle.thin_compact
)

await ctx.send(f"```\n{output}\n```")
````

[image: table 1]

You can choose from many alternate styles.

````py
from table2ascii import table2ascii as t2a, PresetStyle

# In your command:
output = t2a(
    header=["Rank", "Team", "Kills", "Position Pts", "Total"],
    body=[[1, 'Team A', 2, 4, 6], [2, 'Team B', 3, 3, 6], [3, 'Team C', 4, 2, 6]],
    first_col_heading=True
)

await ctx.send(f"```\n{output}\n```")
````

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is probably the closest you will get:

```
embed.add_field(name=f'**{teamname}**', value=f'> Kills: {firstnum}\n> Position Pt: {secondnum}\n> Total Pt: {firstnum+secondnum}',inline=False)
```

The code will output something like this:

[image]

I've set `inline` to `False` and added the `>` character to each of statistics.